# Multi labels classification tools / algorithms that can support distributed computing

Tags: multi-class, multilabel

Currently I'm using mulan library, with random k labels method (in Java) for solving my multi labels classification problem. But I encountered a memory problem due to memory usage.  My training file is quite large (around 2gb ), which causes out of memory error during loading data and training model.

My question is that is there any algorithm/ library (prefer Java), that allows training smaller subsets of labels,  then merging back to the main model?  Or algorithms that can support continously learning.  So a large data file can be divided into multiple training processes.

Thank you.